# How to control JQ display output format for arrays

Tags: jq

I would like to have JQ print out arrays on a single line. My input is a an Avro schema that I want to normalize. This is mainly just to normalize the output in a way that facilitates easier Git diffs as we evolve our schemas. I was able to get down to a filter like this that controls the order of the fields but got stuck with how to force the array to a single line. The format of the output seems to be under JQ's control.

```
jq '{name: .name, fields: .fields | map({ name: .name, type: .type})}' my.json
```

I would like to able to display this:

```
{
  "name": "rm",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "stat_1",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "stat_2",
      "type": [
        "long",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

like this:

```
{
  "name": "rm",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "stat_1",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "stat_2",
      "type": ["long", "null"]  << FLATTENED
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729731/use-jq-to-format-certain-fields-as-compact

Comment: Very difficult to do in jq. There is a ruby gem that comes close: https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON

Answer (score 0):

Since your purpose is to make comparisons simpler, this is what I'd suggest, even though it is not exactly what you want:

```
walk(if type == "array" and all(.[]|type; . != "array" and . != "object")
     then tostring else . end)
```

This has the desired effect of flattening arrays of scalars, though it does so by converting them to strings:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "stat_1",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "stat_2",
      "type": "[\"long\",\"null\"]"
    }
  ],
  "name": "rm"
}
```

#### Variant

If your jq has `isempty` (or if you don't mind adding its definition, e.g. to your ~/.jq), the above can be shortened to:

```
walk(if type == "array" and isempty(.[]|iterables) then tostring else . end)
```

#### isempty

If your jq does not have `isempty`, here is its definition:

```
def isempty(g): 0 == ((label $go | g | (1, break $go)) // 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, This is an interesting approach but I don't necessarily like the string representation side-effect.